# Constructor function for array

Tags: typescript

I am trying to pass a constructor function of a strongly typed array to a method.

The method looks like this:

```
foo<T>(clazz: {new(): T[]}) {
    // ...
}
```

But I was unable to call this method. I tried `foo<MyClass>(MyClass[])` but that just creates a compiler error.

I am trying to use the class MapUtils from [here](http://cloudmark.github.io/Json-Mapping/) to deserialize a JSON array into a strong typed object array.

I am receiving the following JSON:

```
[
    {name: "name1", ...},
    {name: "name2", ...}
]
```

And, using `MapUtils.deserialize`, I want this as the result:

```
[
    <Person> { name: "name1", ... },
    <Person> { name: "name2", ... }
]
```

Comment: A constructor can only create an instance, it can not create an array. Can you show more of the code of what you're trying to do please?

Comment: @NitzanTomer: Please see update (last paragraph)

Comment: That post has a part for [Mapping Arrays](http://cloudmark.github.io/Json-Mapping/#mapping-arrays), that's not good for you? If not, please add a concrete example of the json you get and the class to which you want it to convert to.

Comment: @NitzanTomer: Well, this section is about array properties in the specified type. But I don't see how it helps me with deserializing an array directly.

Comment: It's not exactly clear what your scenario is. Are you getting a json which is an array of objects which should be instantiated? All of this ping pong could have been avoided if you'd just post an example of the json you get and the class you want to create.

Comment: @NitzanTomer: Please see update

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used this `MapUtils` thing, but you can try to do this:

```
MapUtils.deserialize(Array, JSON_DATA);
```

If that doesn't work, then you can simply iterate over the array and for each item use `MapUtils.deserialize`:

```
let arr = [] as Person[];
JSON_DATA.forEach(item => arr.push(MapUtils.deserialize(Person, item)));
```

Or use the `Array.map` method:

```
let arr = JSON_DATA.map(item => MapUtils.deserialize(Person, item));
```